# Find multiple polygons intersecting multiple points

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have 5k polygons in MongoDB and I want to query them with 25 points that are spread out (i.e. not tightly clustered relative to the polygons). **Is there a way to query the database efficiently?**

My understanding is that you can group the points together into a single geojson feature and do an intersection. But this is a bad idea as the bounding box around the set of points will be huge and thus you won't really benefit from any existing index on the polygons.

Alternatively you might be able to do an $or query (I will check myself to see if this is possible), but presumably this is going to treat each bit in isolation, which seems a little inefficient (though much better than the previous option).

Ideally I would like something like the postgis (pseudocode):

```
select * from polygon_table
where geometry in ($1,$2,$3...)
```

as I know that will perform as well as is logically possible (sort of).

[image: cartoon of points and polygons]

Answer (score 1):

25 [$geoIntersects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/) wrapped in [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/index.html).

E.g.

```
db.collection.find({ $or: [
     { loc: {
       $geoIntersects: {
          $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 3, 4 ] } }
       }
     } },
     { loc: {
       $geoIntersects: {
          $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 10, 20 ] } }
     } }

] })
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mentioned in the 3rd paragraph of my question, but I wasn't sure if that was going to give good enough performance and if there was something better.

Comment: I doubt so. Geo indexes are quite good, and 5k documents aren't much either. You can check details with `.explain`.